# Query with TABLE_QUERY is getting more tables than expected

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some tables by day and by hour, called 2015_09_01_00, 2015_09_01_01..., 2015_09_02_00, 2015_09_02_01, etc.

I also created a virtual table for 2015_09_01, 2015_09_02, etc, aggregating them respectively by day.

So, in this context, when I want to query some virtual tables (some days) I have to execute this query for example:

```
SELECT fields FROM TABLE_QUERY(dataset, 'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r"(2015_09_01|2015_09_02)$")')
```

It gives network unreachable error, I guess is messing up between the original tables and the virtual ones since the names are related.

However, if I execute:

```
SELECT table_id FROM dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__ WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r"(2015_09_01|2015_09_02)$")

2015_09_01
2015_09_02
```

it seems that the filter is created successfully.

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Is the error repeatable, and what's the exact text of it?

What happens if you try the query as
"SELECT fields from dataset.2015_09_01, dataset.2015_09_02"
?

Comment: Yes, it is repeatable, the error happens everytime I imply the virtual tables even in a simple SELECT like the one you suggest. It gives the error in the web UI: "Query Failed
Error: Network unreachable. ". It seems the client is disconnected by the server since the query takes too much time, as if it were doing an infinite loop, messing up the tables between the real ones and the virtual ones. Indeed, if I change the name of the virtual tables to daily_[DATE] the queries work perfectly.

Comment: One more question, how exactly did you define the virtual tables / views?

Answer (score 0):

Above example worked for me.
Most likely in your dataset you have other tables with same pattern as you are trying to match.
Try to restrict your regex. For example as below

```
SELECT fields FROM TABLE_QUERY(dataset, 'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r"^(2015_09_01|2015_09_02)$")')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not matter, it seems it's messing up with the virtual and real tables. If I change the name of the daily tables it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the daily views to reference themselves?  Your use of `$` suggested you were thinking about this, but to make sure -- they should reference only the hourly tables.

For example, if you named a view `2014_09_14` when it was based on a `TABLE_QUERY` for

```
'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r"2015_09_14")'
```

then it would reference itself, which does not work.  (This ought to be a clearer error though.)

If you define the view with a `TABLE_QUERY` that can't match itself

```
'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r"2015_09_14_\d\d")'
```

then it should work.  If you select your view's "Details" what is the query that defined it?